# How to plot several plots of numerical solutions on one graph

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a coupled first order system of differential equations which I'm solving numerically (my actual system is more complicated so I use this simple example). I'm trying to plot the solutions for different values of $n$ on one graph:

```
sol = Table[{n, 
   NDSolve[{y'[x] + n z[x] == 0, z'[x] - n y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, 
     z[0] == 1}, {y, z}, {x, 0, 1}]}, {n, 1, 2}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol[[1]][[2]]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol[[2]][[2]]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Table[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol[[n]][[2]]], {n, 1, 2}], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

The last line doing this gives me an error "Part::pkspec1: The expression n cannot be used as a part specification." However I can still plot solutions for different $n$s on different graphs, as illustrated by running the previous two lines. What is going wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have a look at `Dimensions[sol[[1]][[2]]]`. You can change the last replacement to `y[x] /. sol[[n]][[2]]][[1]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion `ParametricNDSolve` is the ideal command for such situation.

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] + n z[x] == 0, z'[x] - n y[x] == 0, 
       y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1}, {y, z}, {x, 0, 1}, {n}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[n][x] /. sol, {n, 1, 2}]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Altenative `ParametricNDSolveValue`

```
Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] + n z[x] == 0, z'[x] - n y[x] == 0,y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}, {n}]

Plot[Table[ Y[n][x] , {n, 1, 2}], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]